# How am I using malloc incorrectly here?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am trying to learn how to properly allocate memory at runtime in C99.

I've written as minimal an example as I think will be instructive as to what I am trying to do. For some reason the "inner" calls to `malloc` where chunks of memory of size `sizeof(letter_t)` are allocated only do what I expect (ie. allocate the memory) for the first element in the array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct letter_t {
    char *from;
    int lines;
} letter_t;

typedef struct letterbox_t {
    char *name;
    int n_letters;
    struct letter_t **letters;
} letterbox_t;

int main() {

    char *name[]    = { "amy", "bob", "claud" };
    int n_letters[] = { 1,     3,     2 };

    // layout memory and populate letterbox_t array
    struct letterbox_t *letterboxes;
    letterboxes = malloc(sizeof(letterbox_t) * 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        letterboxes[i].name = name[i];
        letterboxes[i].n_letters = n_letters[i];

        struct letter_t *letters[n_letters[i]];
        for (int j = 0; j < n_letters[i]; j++) {
            letters[j] = malloc(sizeof(letter_t));
        }
        letterboxes[i].letters = letters;
    }

    // populate letter_t array for each letterbox_t
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < letterboxes[i].n_letters; j++) {
            // =========================================
            letterboxes[i].letters[j]->from = "spammer";
            // =========================================
            // the above line fails for i = 1, j = 1
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s has %d letters from\n", letterboxes[i].name, letterboxes[i].n_letters);
        for (int j = 0; j < letterboxes[i].n_letters; j++) {
            printf("  %s\n", letterboxes[i].letters[j]->from);
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

When `j` on the inner loop reaches `1`, all I see is garbage memory. Here is some GDB output as an illustration.

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at example.c:40
40            letterboxes[i].letters[j]->from = "spammer";
(gdb) p i
$1 = 1
(gdb) p j
$2 = 1
(gdb) p letterboxes[i].letters[j]
$3 = (struct letter_t *) 0x400604 <main+228>
(gdb) p *letterboxes[i].letters[j]
$4 = {from = 0x904d8b48ac7d6348 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x904d8b48ac7d6348>, lines = -117143224}
```

Comment: `struct letter_t* letters[n_letters[i]];` does not match `struct letter_t** letters;` Since `letters` is `struct letter_t**`, you need to allocate the number of needed `pointers` before allocating and assigning the address of a block of memory to each `letters[i]`.

Comment: The problem is here:  `struct letter_t* letters[n_letters[i]];`  This is local storage.  It is not defined when it goes out of scope.  You need to use `malloc` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very large number of small problems. To begin, as mentioned in my comment, your attempt to allocate for `struct letter_t* letters[n_letters[i]];` does not match `struct letter_t** letters;`

Next, before going further, a nit, the `'*'` belongs with the variable name, not the type in most cases. Why?

```
int* a, b, c;
```

Above, you are certainly not declaring 3-pointers to `int`. Instead you are declaring the integer-pointer `a`, and integers `b, c`. Much clearer written as:

```
int *a, b, c;
```

When you allocate memory, you must validate the allocation succeeded -- Every Time, e.g.

```
    size_t n_people = sizeof name / sizeof *name;

    // layout memory and populate letterbox_t array
    struct letterbox_t *letterboxes;
    /* allocate letterboxes for each of the people */
    letterboxes = malloc (sizeof *letterboxes * n_people);
    if (!letterboxes) {     /* validate Every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-letterboxes");
        return 1;
    }
```

You now have storage for 3 `letterbox_t` allocated and can begin working on the contents. You can assign the names and number of letters to each:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_people; i++) {

        /* assigning pointer to string literal */
        letterboxes[i].name = name[i];
        letterboxes[i].n_letters = n_letters[i];    /* int assignment */
```

(**note:** Be careful. Understand you are assigning the *String Literal* from `name[i]` to each `letterboxes[i].name`. That means `letterboxes[i].name` cannot be modified and should not be freed. Generally you should allocate storage for `name` and copy)

`letterboxes[i].letters` is a *pointer-to-pointer* to `letter_t`. Meaning you must allocate pointers first, and then allocate storage for each `letter` and assign the starting address for that memory block to each of the pointers, e.g. `letterboxes[i].letters[j]`. For example:

```
        /* allocate letterboxes[i].n_letters pointers */
        letterboxes[i].letters =
            malloc (sizeof *letterboxes[i].letters * letterboxes[i].n_letters);
        if (!letterboxes[i].letters) { /* validate allocation */
            perror ("malloc-letterboxes.letters");
            return 1;
        }

        /* allocate letters per-pointer */
        for (int j = 0; j < letterboxes[i].n_letters; j++) {
            letterboxes[i].letters[j] = 
                            malloc (sizeof *letterboxes[i].letters[j]);
            if (!letterboxes[i].letters[j]) {
                perror ("malloc-letterboxes[i].letters[j]");
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

Now with all your storage properly allocated ***and validated***, you can populate each of the letters to each of the people and then output the results, e.g.

```
    // populate letter_t array for each letterbox_t
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_people; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < letterboxes[i].n_letters; j++) {
            letterboxes[i].letters[j]->from = "spammer";
            /* added lines just to complete assignments */
            letterboxes[i].letters[j]->lines = letterboxes[i].n_letters * 10;
        }
    }

    // output all letterboxes and letters
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_people; i++) {
        printf("%s has %d letters from\n", 
                        letterboxes[i].name, letterboxes[i].n_letters);
        for (int j = 0; j < letterboxes[i].n_letters; j++) {
            printf("  %s  %d\n", letterboxes[i].letters[j]->from,
                                letterboxes[i].letters[j]->lines);
        }
    }
```

Once you are done using your allocated memory, it is up to You to see that it is properly freed. (which becomes critical as your programs grow and you begin allocating within functions). Failure to free what you use leads to *memory leaks* in programs. To that end, it would make sense to write a simple function to free a `letterbox_t` completely, e.g.

```
/* simple function to free single letterbox_t completely */
void freeletterbox (letterbox_t *l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < l->n_letters; i++)
        free (l->letters[i]);

    free (l->letters);
}
```

Then when you are done with the memory, you can `free()` it, e.g.

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_people; i++)   /* free each letterbox */
        freeletterbox (&letterboxes[i]);
    free (letterboxes);                     /* free pointers */
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct letter_t {
    char *from;
    int lines;
} letter_t;

typedef struct letterbox_t {
    char *name;
    int n_letters;
    struct letter_t **letters;
} letterbox_t;

/* simple function to free single letterbox_t completely */
void freeletterbox (letterbox_t *l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < l->n_letters; i++)
        free (l->letters[i]);

    free (l->letters);
}

int main (void) {

    char *name[]    = {"amy", "bob", "claud"};
    int n_letters[] = {1,     3,     2};
    size_t n_people = sizeof name / sizeof *name;

    // layout memory and populate letterbox_t array
    struct letterbox_t *letterboxes;
    /* allocate letterboxes for each of the people */
    letterboxes = malloc (sizeof *letterboxes * n_people);
    if (!letterboxes) {     /* validate Every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-letterboxes");
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_people; i++) {

        /* assigning pointer to string literal */
        letterboxes[i].name = name[i];
        letterboxes[i].n_letters = n_letters[i];    /* int assignment */

        /* allocate letterboxes[i].n_letters pointers */
        letterboxes[i].letters =
            malloc (sizeof *letterboxes[i].letters * letterboxes[i].n_letters);
        if (!letterboxes[i].letters) { /* validate allocation */
            perror ("malloc-letterboxes.letters");
            return 1;
        }

        /* allocate letters per-pointer */
        for (int j = 0; j < letterboxes[i].n_letters; j++) {
            letterboxes[i].letters[j] = 
                            malloc (sizeof *letterboxes[i].letters[j]);
            if (!letterboxes[i].letters[j]) {
                perror ("malloc-letterboxes[i].letters[j]");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // populate letter_t array for each letterbox_t
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_people; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < letterboxes[i].n_letters; j++) {
            letterboxes[i].letters[j]->from = "spammer";
            /* added lines just to complete assignments */
            letterboxes[i].letters[j]->lines = letterboxes[i].n_letters * 10;
        }
    }

    // output all letterboxes and letters
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_people; i++) {
        printf("%s has %d letters from\n", 
                        letterboxes[i].name, letterboxes[i].n_letters);
        for (int j = 0; j < letterboxes[i].n_letters; j++) {
            printf("  %s  %d\n", letterboxes[i].letters[j]->from,
                                letterboxes[i].letters[j]->lines);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_people; i++)   /* free each letterbox */
        freeletterbox (&letterboxes[i]);
    free (letterboxes);                     /* free pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/letters
amy has 1 letters from
  spammer  10
bob has 3 letters from
  spammer  30
  spammer  30
  spammer  30
claud has 2 letters from
  spammer  20
  spammer  20
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/letters
==4735== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4735== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4735== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4735== Command: ./bin/letters
==4735==
amy has 1 letters from
  spammer  10
bob has 3 letters from
  spammer  30
  spammer  30
  spammer  30
claud has 2 letters from
  spammer  20
  spammer  20
==4735==
==4735== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4735==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4735==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 216 bytes allocated
==4735==
==4735== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4735==
==4735== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4735== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
struct letter_t* letters[n_letters[i]];
```

to this:

```
struct letter_t** letters = malloc(n_letters[i] * sizeof(struct letter_t*));
```

because, as @TomKarzes commented, you create `letters` inside the body of the for loop, thus it goes out of scope once the loop terminates.

For that reason, you need to dynamically allocate memory for it, so that the memory doesn't get deallocated after the loop terminates.

PS: Do not forget to free your memory at the end of your program, following the reverse order from the order you followed when you were allocating dynamically memory.